# Set bulder notatation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If we consider a set $X = [1,3] \times [1,3]$ which should be sketched on the plane $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.
I am wondering how to describe this set using set builder notation.

I tried;

$$X = \{(a,b)\, | \, a\in [1,3] \; and \; b \in [1,3]  \}$$

Would this be correct?

Comment: It's an acceptable notation, but whether or not it is *set builder* notation depends what you call "set builder notation" of the following three: $\{x\in A\,\mid\, P(x)\}$, $\{x\,\mid\, P(x)\}$  and $\{f(y)\,\mid\, y\in S\}:=\{x\,\mid\, \exists y\in S, x=f(y)\}$.

Comment: That will work but you can also write $X= \{(a,b)| 1\le a\le 3 \text{ and }1\le b\le 3\}$

Comment: ...or preferably $X= \{(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2\mid1\le a\le 3 \text{ and }1\le b\le 3\}.$